# How do you unmerge images in sketch when using Union Subtract Intersect or Difference?

Tags: sketch-app

Once you combine two shapes using Union, Subtract, Intersect, Difference, how do you unmerge them or ungroup them?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the triangle to the left of the new compound shape you created you will see each of the child shapes that it's made of. If you drag them outside of that group it will ungroup them.